# How do I have text in a winforms textbox be prefixed with unchangable text?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have an application that allows the creation and running of automated testing scripts.  The test scripts themselves are xml files that are meant to be portable, which means that once one is configured it should work on any computer.

One of the configuration settings saved in the xml files is the location of builds to copy over.  Depending on the setup of the computer root folder can be different, for example on my computer I may be looking at `F:\Builds\2-QA\ClientA` where as another machine it requires `\\server1\Public\Builds\2-QA\ClientA`, and if the server changes it would be `\newserver\Public\Builds\2-QA\ClientA'.

I solve this descrepency by only having the user save the last part (e.g. `2-QA\ClientA`) in the xml, and the root is resolved by an application setting in App.Config.

The problem with this is that in the GUI where the user enters the application source directory, it's not clear what part of the folder structure they have to enter and what is resolved by App.Config.

Therefore, what I would like is my textbox to have the root directory auto-populated inside, but in a read-only way.  So for instance, the textbox will display `F:\Builds\` and the user can add the folder structure they want at the end, but they cannot delete any part of the `F:\Builds\`.  When saving I intend to strip off the `F:\Builds\` part, but that can't be relied upon if they are able to (intentionally or not) delete characters from `F:\Builds\`.

Any suggestions on accomplishing this?

Comment: I think a label would be alright for this.

Comment: You could add a label containing F:\Builds\ to the left of the textbox.

Comment: The problem with a label is I can't guarantee how wide the text in the app setting is, unless it's on a completely seperate line as the textbox, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: you could try this too http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Comment: (this is not a solution to your problem, but an idea) You could also make the text box contain only the relative part, and then display the absolute path in a separate label which would update as user typed. That would make it pretty clear what the absolute destination is.

Comment: Oh, now there's a cleaner idea

Comment: @Groo, if you submit that as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.  I think that's the cleanest, easist, and most user friendly way to accomplish my main goal

Answer (score 2):

Try using a MaskedTextBox and set its [Mask property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) to the string you want prefixed.

Something like:  F:\Builds\LLLLLLLLLLLL

Comment: Would'nt that just limit the input sequences? How does it make indelible text appear to the left of a textbox?

Comment: @anirudh4444 It wouldn't. The OP said he wanted text _in_ his TextBox "in a read-only way" with the user only able to add text after.

Comment: I didn't know about masked text boxes, but how can I make the amount to the right hand side an infinite amount, instead of adding a lot of Ls at the end?

Comment: @KallDrexx Frankly, I don't know that much about MaskedTextBoxes either. You can put a bunch of L's at the end.  After all, there is an OS imposed limit to the length of path.

Answer (score 0):

My thought:

Forget about making it unmodifiable.

Have a function that runs on text change. If the prefix is N characters long, change the first N characters of the text box to the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a label in front of the text box. The label would contain the text you wouldn't want changed which makes it clear to the user that you want the next bit entered into the text box.

Comment: That's hard to do.  I don't know at design time what the text is, so I can't predict how wide I need the label to be, and since it won't scroll like a text box, a large value with a dynamic width will push the textbox off to the right too much.