# Permanent prefix in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to have a permanent prefix input in the textbox. In my case, I want to have the following prefix:

`DOMAIN\`

So that users can only have to type their username after the domain prefix. It's not something I have to do, or pursue but my question is more out of curiosity.

I was trying to come up with some logic to do this on the `TextChangedEvent` however, this means I need to know which characters have been deleted where and then pre-append `DOMAIN\` to whatever their input is - I can't work out the logic for this so I can't post what I have tried apart from where I got to.

```
public void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!TextBox1.Text.Contains(@"DOMAIN\")
  {
    //Handle putting Domain in here along with the text that would be determined as the username
  }
}
```

I've looked on the internet and can't find anything, [How do I have text in a winforms textbox be prefixed with unchangable text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298083/how-do-i-have-text-in-a-winforms-textbox-be-prefixed-with-unchangable-text) was trying to do a similar thing but the answers don't really help.

Any ideas on how I can keep the prefix `DOMAIN\` in a `TextBox`?

Comment: Use a RichTextBox and do a SelectionProtected on the first seven characters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the KISS principle is indicated here.  Trying to catch key presses just won't do anything when the user uses Ctrl+V or the context menu's Cut and Paste commands.  Simply restore the text when anything happened that fudged the prefix:

```
    private const string textPrefix = @"DOMAIN\";

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!textBox1.Text.StartsWith(textPrefix)) {
            textBox1.Text = textPrefix;
            textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

And help the user avoid editing the prefix by accident:

```
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, I just came back to here from one of my bookmarks because I wanted to use this feature. Just a small issue, the first character gets deleted and replaced by the prefix when the user types in something and that could cause typing errors for sensitive data. This could be solved by modifying textBox1.Text = textPrefix; with textBox1.Text = textPrefix + textBox1.Text;. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not see in the event args of the textChanged what the value was before and the new value and if the `Domain\` is not there in the new value, then keep the old one.

Or, why not just show the `Domain\` as a label in front of the TextBox and just prepend it in code behind so that the final text is something like `Domain\<username>`.

Comment: Probably would be more work than the solution I just found, a label might work but I don't find it as neat as prefixing the textbox that data entry is happening in :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I sort of solved this once I asked the question... I won't delete the question incase anybody else has the same question in the future, because I couldn't find a suitable answer. I set the `Text` to `Domain\` and then used the `KeyPress` event.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = (textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(Cursor.Position) < 7);
}
```

I tend to keep working once I ask, instead of letting people do all the work for me :)

Comment: Use the Paste command to see this code fail.  Ctrl+V or Paste from the context menu.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't test it to that extent, thanks for pointing that out :P

Answer (score 1):

How about a reusable custom TextBox control. There are comments in the code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Prefix = @"DOMAIN\";
    }
}

class PrefixedTextBox : TextBox
{
    private string _prefix = String.Empty;
    public string Prefix
    {
        get { return _prefix; }
        set
        {
            _prefix = value;
            Text = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't allow Backspace and Delete if the only text is Prefix
        if (Text == Prefix && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back || e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete))
            e.Handled = true;

        // If home key is pressed set cursor just after the prefix
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Home)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SelectionStart = Prefix.Length;
        }

        // Don't allow cursor to be moved inside Prefix
        if (SelectionStart <= Prefix.Length && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up))
            e.Handled = true;

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureCursorPosition();
        base.OnClick(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureCursorPosition();

        // this was checked OnKeyDown. This prevents deleting and writing back behaviour
        if (Text == Prefix && e.KeyChar == '\b')
            e.Handled = true;

        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Yet, some how an invalid text is entered fix it by just displaying the Prefix
        if (!Text.StartsWith(Prefix))
            Text = Prefix;

        base.OnKeyUp(e);
    }

    private void EnsureCursorPosition()
    {
        // Never allow cursor position before Prefix
        if (SelectionStart < Prefix.Length)
            SelectionStart = Text.Length;
    }
}
```